# MDX query to display this year's sale along with the last year's sale

Tags: mdx

Here's my query. I want to display this year's data from week 12 to week 24 along with last year's data from week 12 to week 24. But I got the same data for both years even I had the "prevMember". Could you help me?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Net Sales This Year] AS ([Measures].[Ticket Net Sales],[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].currentmember.prevmember)  

SELECT {[Measures].[Ticket Net Sales],[Measures].[Net Sales Last Year]} on 0,

NON EMPTY {([Concepts].[Concept Name].[Concept Name],[Locations].[Department Name].[Department Name],
            [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members,[Date].[Week Of Year].&[12]:[Date].[Week Of Year].&[24])} on 1

FROM spbi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PARALLELPERIOD()` function to achieve this.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Net Sales This Year] AS ([Measures].[Ticket Net Sales],[Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember.PrevMember)  

SELECT {[Measures].[Ticket Net Sales],[Measures].[Net Sales Last Year]} ON 0,

NON EMPTY [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members * [Date].[Week Of Year].&[12]:[Date].[Week Of Year].&[24]) ON 1

FROM spbi
```